# Cloud Function not able to continue after exception encountered

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-3.8, try-except, google-cloud-scheduler

So I have made a cloud function responsible to read files over SFTP server and then push them to Google BigQuery. There are 4-5 relevant files in the directory at a time and are sometimes erronous. To cater their errors, I have enclosed reading it in a `try-except` block. Which works locally and when script is run on a Compute Engine Instance (where it was hosted before I tried moving it to Cloud Functions. On Cloud Functions, it stops running after it encounters error on first file. Attached is the logs screenshot as well. I have tried increasing time limit for the function and memory allocated to it, however it does not help.

Whole Script:

```
import pysftp
import json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
def push_files():
  client = bigquery.Client()
  remote_path='/home/user/s/'
  cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
  cnopts.hostkeys = None    
  sftp=pysftp.Connection('host_ip',  private_key='private_key.pem' , username = 'user', cnopts=cnopts)
  files = [file for file in sftp.listdir(remote_path) if not file.__contains__('.ipynb')
        and not file.__contains__('sgp') and not file.__contains__('booking')
        and not file.__contains__('web') and not file.__contains__('SHIPPING')
        and not file.__contains__('addresses_v2') and not file.__contains__('fc_cust')]

  print(json.dumps(dict(
            severity="NOTICE",
            message=f"These are files to push {files}",)))

  for file in files:
    try:
      df = pd.read_csv(sftp.open(f"{remote_path}/{file}"), sep='\t', engine='python')
      table_id = f"sftp_data.{file}"
      job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
          df, table_id
      )

      # Wait for the load job to complete.
      job.result()
      print(json.dumps(dict(
            severity="NOTICE",
            message=f"pushed {file}",)))
                        
    except Exception as e:
      print(json.dumps(dict(
            severity="NOTICE",
            message=f"could not push {file} because of {e.__str__()}",)))

  return "Pushed Files!"


def main(request):
  print('request: recieved')
  response = push_files()
  return f'Executed Request:{request} and {response}'
```

And here's the logs of cloud functions:
[image]

Comment: It seems a encoding type problem. Did you try this way?

Comment: Yes but it should move on regardless of the problem because of try-except and it is not.

Comment: Visually, I cannot find anything wrong with your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation. Is the code in your question intended **exactly** the same way?

Comment: Its a copy-paste although a few details changed like IP and username however it should not change the indentation

Comment: Is the function returning this formatted string **return f'Executed Request:{request} and {response}'**? The logs show that the function returned normally with status code 200.

Comment: No since I chose the main function as entry point, its not returning it

Comment: What is it returning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239589/discussion-between-hamza-and-john-hanley).

Comment: A Cloud Function should not completely stop after encountering an Exception. I tested raising exceptions in a similar manner as your function might, and it does continue correctly. How much memory and time are allocated to your function after you increased those two values? Also, based on the [pysftp](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/master/README.rst) repo, it has not been tested with Python 3.8; were you using Python 3.8 locally and on GCE? It would also be useful to look at your `requirements.txt` file used by your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `continue` to resume the loop

```
for file in files:
    try:
      df = pd.read_csv(sftp.open(f"{remote_path}/{file}"), sep='\t', engine='python')
      table_id = f"sftp_data.{file}"
      job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
          df, table_id
      )

      # Wait for the load job to complete.
      job.result()
      print(json.dumps(dict(
            severity="NOTICE",
            message=f"pushed {file}",)))
                        
    except Exception as e:
      print(json.dumps(dict(
            severity="NOTICE",
            message=f"could not push {file} because of {e.__str__()}",)))
      continue
```